# Asymptote: Project object with planeproject and XYplane

Tags: asymptote, technical-drawing

I need to draw the figure like the following:

[image]

The idea is to first draw blue rectangle and then project it to XY plane. My current code is pasted below.

```
import graph3;
import three;
settings.outformat="pdf";
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-2,0.5);
limits((-4,-4,-0.2),(4,4,3.5));
size3(8cm,8cm,4cm);

// Draw axis
xaxis3("$x$",Arrow3);
yaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
zaxis3("$z$",Arrow3);

// Draw blue rectangle
path3 rect1=(0.5,0.5,2)--(1.5,0.5,2)--(1.5,1.5,2)--(0.5,1.5,2)--cycle;
draw(rect1,blue);

// Construct projection and draw red rectangle
// XYplane is defined in three library
transform3 proj=planeproject(XYplane);
path3 proj=proj*rect1;
draw(proj,red);
```

Compilation terminated with the error:

```
no matching function 'planeproject(triple(pair z))'
```

Any idea or pointer how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `planeproject` expects is simply the normal vector to the plane. `XYplane` is an object of type `triple(pair)`: it's actually a function that maps (x,y) to (x,y,0). The normal vector you want is simply `Z`.

Here's working code, obtained by replacing `planeproject(XYplane)` by `planeproject(Z)`:

```
import graph3;
import three;
settings.outformat="pdf";
currentprojection=orthographic(1,-2,0.5);
limits((-4,-4,-0.2),(4,4,3.5));
size3(8cm,8cm,4cm);

// Draw axis
xaxis3("$x$",Arrow3);
yaxis3("$y$",Arrow3);
zaxis3("$z$",Arrow3);

// Draw blue rectangle
path3 rect1=(0.5,0.5,2)--(1.5,0.5,2)--(1.5,1.5,2)--(0.5,1.5,2)--cycle;
draw(rect1,blue);

// Construct projection and draw red rectangle
// XYplane is defined in three library
transform3 proj=planeproject(Z);
path3 proj=proj*rect1;
draw(proj,red);
```

The result:

[image]

Another general tip: It's generally preferable to make changes like `settings.outformat="pdf";` before you start your imports, since some of the modules do different things depending on the settings.